# How to reverse index a dictionary containing list of values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d = { "claims": [
              "Georg",
              "Bob",
              "Jeny",
              "John",
              "Catherin",
              "Tommen",
              "Linda",
              "Bran",
              "Sansa",
              "Ross",
              "Lyana",
              "Gilly",
              "Daario",
              "Sam",
              "Tyrion",
              "Peter",
              "Arya",
              "Sandra",
              "Catelyn"
            ],
     "names" : ["Lyana",
              "Gilly",
              "Daario",
              "Sam",
              "Tyrion",
              "Peter",
              "Arya",
              "Sandra",
              "Catelyn"]

          }

my_dict = {value: key for key in d for value in d[key]}
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Did you try to run your code? Because, AFAIK, it works fine...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta There are overlapping values which will result for some keys to be overwritten in the new dict.

Comment: @BramAppel The OP did not state that that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend the use of a dict comprehension in this case for the sake of readability. The dict-method 'setdefault' is the method you are looking for.

```py
d = { "claims": [
              "Georg",
              "Bob",
              "Jeny",
              "John",
              "Catherin",
              "Tommen",
              "Linda",
              "Bran",
              "Sansa",
              "Ross",
              "Lyana",
              "Gilly",
              "Daario",
              "Sam",
              "Tyrion",
              "Peter",
              "Arya",
              "Sandra",
              "Catelyn"
            ],
     "names" : ["Lyana",
              "Gilly",
              "Daario",
              "Sam",
              "Tyrion",
              "Peter",
              "Arya",
              "Sandra",
              "Catelyn"]

          }

new_dict = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        # return empty list if key not found, thereafter append 'names' or 'claims' to the returned value
        new_dict.setdefault(i, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict() 
    for key in d:
       for item in d[key]:
            if item not in inverse: 
                inverse[item] = [key] 
            else: 
                inverse[item].append(key) 
    return inverse
invert_dict(d)
```